Separate a column with comma delimited values into multiple rows in BigQuery
I have this table in my data warehouse



ID
Type
Name




1
Fruit
Banana, Apple, Berry


2
Vegetable
Carrot, Tomato



I want it to query it to be like the following:



ID
Type
Name




1
Fruit
Banana


1
Fruit
Apple


1
Fruit
Berry


2
Vegetable
Carrot


2
Vegetable
Tomato



i tried to use split finction but it didn't work, and I found people mentioned unnest but this function is not available  in bigquery
enter image description here
enter image description here

Here is a full solution:
create table `test.produce`
as 
select 1 as id, "fruit" as type, ["banana", "apple", "berry"] as name
union all
select 2, "vegetable", ["carrot", "tomato"];

select L.* except(name), name from `test.produce` as L left join unnest(name) as name

BigQuery supports unnest just fine.

This will work but what if i have a huge table? -- I added a screenshot from the error i get when i use unnest in bigquery

Your pasted error is ambiguous.  Paste exactly the SQL statement(s) you are trying to execute when the error is returned.
